# Display Tag : How to display Images with Display tag

Tags: jsp

I have a Forum Web  Site , where people can Post the Content with they can upload Pictures also .
So if  any user searches the forum using any keyword  , i want to display the Search results  on to the JSP page using the display tag ( As of this , i wanted to display the Pictures also .

But i am not sure how using Display Tag the  Pictures can also be displayed on the Search results

Please share your experiences , as how can i implement this requirement using Display tag , Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display tag has nothing to do with pictures. Its goal is to generate tables. If you want to display some picture in a column of a table, then use the following code:

```
<display:table id="myBean" ...>
    <display:column>
        <img src="<c:url value='${myBean.pictureUrl}'/>" />
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

This assumes that the beans you iterate over have a method `public String getPictureUrl()` which returns an absolute or context-relative URL of a picture to display for this bean.

Comment: Thanks for the response , i will be  getting the Image data in a Binary Format from MySQL Database with the Other data like name , ID , Type of Request --- , now my question is that how this Image can be in a URL Format ?? Please let me know . thanks .

Comment: Your JSP should generate HTML code containing `<img src="imageServlet?imageId=someImageId"/>`, and you should implement a servlet mapped to the `imageServlet` path, which gets the image bytes from the database and sends them (with the appropriate content type) to the servlet response's output stream.

Comment: Thanks , that was very much helpful .